# Как расшифровать utf-8 записанный в виде обычной строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

У меня есть utf-8 символы, но они записаны не в виде байтов, а в виде обычной строки

например: b'\xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82!'

Как мне перевести это в обычные буквы?

Comment: У вас как раз не строка, а байты. Декодировать как байты - с помощью `.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Да, но эти байты буквально содержатся внутри строки например: str = " b'\xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82!'"

Comment: Вопрос в том, как они туда попали? Скорее всего у вас откуда-то приходят байты, вы их зачем-то оборачиваете в вызов str(), а потом не знаете что с этим делать.

Comment: Я "шифрую" Строки переводя их в utf-8 ведь человеческий глаз не сможет сходу перевести их в обычный текст, исходные строки естественно потом удаляются

Comment: Сомнительный способ "шифрования". ASCII символы остаются без изменений, появляется мусор в виде кавычек и `b` и т.п. Уж лучше перевести в hex типа так `codecs.encode('text to encode'.encode('utf-8'), 'hex').decode('ascii')`

Comment: @Artem-_- вопрос нужно уточнять кнопкой "править", а не в комментариях. В тексте вопроса сейчас совсем не то, что вы хотите спросить. В итоге отвечают не то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Декодировать можно так:

```
F = b'\xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82!'
print(F.decode('utf-8'))
```